# Connecting java to database to make a login form

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, netbeans

Right now i'm making a kinda inventory database project. 
So i wanna ask what is the right way to connect java to database(mysql) in this case i use mysql that i installed from appserv and i manage it through phpmyadmin. and i'm using Netbeans IDE

so i surf the internet:

To Connect database :

1. i add the jdbc library to my library
2. i made the new connection in netbeans (i already made database in mysql)
3. i fill my port etc

To Test The Connection

```js
import java.sql.*;
public class connection {
    public static void main(String[]args){
   try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Succeed Load Driver ..");
}catch (ClassNotFoundException ex ){
    System.out.println("error"+ex);
}
   try {
       String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data";
       Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","password");
       System.out.println("Success Connect To Database");
   }catch(SQLException e){
       System.out.println("error"+e);
   }
         
}
}
```

> Question

1. is it the proper way to connect java to sql?
2. is it the proper way to test the connection?
3. I already design the login form ( jframe ) netbeans , the problem is how to get data from sql.so user can login but only for user that registered in the sql.

i'm just beginner 
sorry for my bad english anyway

Comment: Did you run the code? What did it do?  Your are probably close to correct for the first 2 questions, but the third is off-topic as it is much too broad a topic for StackOverflow.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: @JimGarrison its succeed to connect to driver and database. So i'm already in the right way?? Sorry for the third question. I already clearing my question hopefully you can take a look again thank you for comment.

Comment: Yes, but what you have done so far is trivially tiny compared to the task of making a login page if you have never written a servlet/jsp and worked with a container such as Tomcat.  There's probably a month or two of learning curve if you're starting from scratch and are a strong developer.

Comment: @JimGarrison then can you suggest me what should i learn first for the first?? Cause i'm just in high school and have no idea at all about java, but i'm planning to take com.science Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.sql.*;

public class connectToMySQL {


public static void main(String[] args) {
     Connection con = null;
     Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library";
            //String url      = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:portnumber/DatabaseName

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, yourUsername, yourPassword); 
          System.out.println("Connected with the database!");
          System.out.println("Creating statement...");

          //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
          stmt.close();
          con.close();


}
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());

   }
   }
   }
```

and to answer your 3rd question you going to need to learn how to use Insert, and Select statements, the methods and terms your going to need to know in Java are preparedStatements, SQL....

Example

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO userinformation (first_name, last_name)" +
                    "VALUES ( ?, ?)";
          PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
          preparedStatement.setString(1, "John");
          preparedStatement.setString(2, "Appleseed");
          preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

"String sql" refers to the sql statement I'm using to contact with my database, userinformation is the database I'm inserting my information into, than the question marks are parameters in which are set at "preparedStatement.setString(1(1 is referring to the parameter, so this string will replace the first value) which in the example is John and than the 2nd value will be "Appleseed"
than the next line executes the query with that information, please email me for further information......... nmarotta1999@gmail.com, hope this helps.

Comment: and actually your code works, make sure that you have a JDBC driver installed and in your class path

Comment: Thank you for your answer. okay about the 3rd question. i need to learn sql language? i know a lil bit of sql. Am i already in the correct way to learn java? i'm beginner